# Creating multiple directories in Bash script while unzipping

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am using Bash script in Ubuntu.
I have several `.mbz` files which are basically `zip files` so I want to unzip them with `tar`.  How i can tar them with a loop and create a directory for each of them.

e.x this is how i did for one file

`mkdir course4444
 tar -xvzf course4.mbz -C course4444
 cd course4444
 tar -cvzf course4444.mbz *`

But, I have more than 6 .mbz files so I want for each of them to have a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert on mbz files. but for simply doing something to several files you can use this pattern.

```
for mbzfile in course01.mbz course02.mbz c3.mbz c4.mbz c5.mbz c6.mbz; do
     echo "file : $mbzfile"
done
```

will print :

```
file : course01.mbz
file : course02.mbz
file : c3.mbz
file : c4.mbz
file : c5.mbz
file : c6.mbz
```

this means you would do this:

```
for mbzfile in course01.mbz course02.mbz c3.mbz c4.mbz c5.mbz c6.mbz; do
     mkdir "${mbzfile%%.mbz}"
     tar -xvzf "$mbzfile" -C "${mbzfile%%.mbz}"
     cd "${mbzfile%%.mbz}"
     tar -cvzf "$mbzfile" *
done
```

albeit I am not clear what the last `tar` command should do (since you speak about extracting the content while this would recreate some content.

Comment: Yes I have to because mbz file extracts a compressed file and within it there is a gzip file so, via tar this is doable.
But, I thank you for your effort, it works out (y)